# Partition table messed up. Cant see any partition using Gparted, though everything works?

Tags: 12.04, disk

Yesterday I was trying to install Mageia Linux along with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10. After several tries I finally installed Mageia and created an entry for the Mageia boot-loader in the Windows boot manager.

The problem is, though everything seems to be working perfectly, when I open Gparted it says that there are no partitions on the hard disk.

Here's a screen-shot:

[image]

What is wrong, and how can I fix this without losing any data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the same Mageia OS installation disk and again start installing Mageia, but this time uncheck all ntfs/ext4 partitions from changing labels/auto mount in Mageia. If you have changed primary partitions into logical partitions then, delete/create new partitions from the previous ones and choose "force as primary" and then continue the installation.

Make it a minimal installation as you are going to remove it. Wait for the installation to complete successfully. After completion, boot into Ubuntu or run Ubuntu live DVD. Using Gparted from there reformat the Mageia partitions. Don't change anything except formatting. After formatting completes delete those partitions. Now from the free space you can again be able to create primary partitions.

This will fix this error. But there will be consequences

[image]

Answer (score 0):

why do you need two linux systems anyhow? if you just want to try it, unplug your hard drive, plug another one in, instal it and try it, if you like it better, reinstall it back on the other one again, delete the Ubuntu partitions, leave windows on there if you have it there, format partioms for ubuntu or delete them and create new ones for Mageia, format them all and then install Mageia 1,2,3 or 4 and it will automatically see window, I've been doing all this since 2003 and I have 5 differnt harddrives for my laptop with 5 different Linx sysems on each of them, it don't take long to switch a haerddrive on a laptop, or a usb flashdrive which is just as giood or better!!
Pegasus